# How to make Xcode Archive use the right configuration information?

Tags: xcode, configuration, archive, target

My Mac app has two Targets.  When I attempt to Archive the second Target, Xcode always uses the configuration info for the first Target  (Bundle ID, Version, and Build)  even though I have selected the second Target.

By configuration I mean the "General" options displayed when clicking on the project name in the Project Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong scheme (whatever that is).  To set the right scheme, use the Scheme menu (just to the right of the square Stop button on Xcode's menu bar).